# What does Vector.size() returns exactly? Can we Compare it with an Integer directly?

Tags: c++, list, vector

I have an Int called "ListIndex" to store the value of the index, and a pointer of Vector called "EnqueryList".

So If I tried to compare ListIndex with (*EnqueryList).size() directly, it will give me the wrong result, but if I tried to store the value of (*EnqueryList).size() in another integer "Length" and then compare the value of length and value of ListIndex, the result would be correct, why is that?

```
    cout<<ListIndex<<":"<<(*Enquery).size()-1<<":"<<(ListIndex<(*Enquery).size()-1)<<"\n";
    cout<<ListIndex<<":"<<length<<":"<<(ListIndex<length)<<"\n";
```

The Result of the above Couts:

-1:2:0

-1:2:1

Comment: This is documented.   The function returns `size_type` which is always an unsigned type, usually `std::size_t` 
 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector?msclkid=8067cef8cefc11ecabfd1d8f9bac437c

Answer (score 0):

> What does Vector.size() returns exactly?

Assuming that you actually mean `std::vector::size`, it returns the number of elements the vector contains. Same applies to the `size` member function of all standard containers.